# is it possible to give an empty object in react state for the init default value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using react `"react": "^17.0.0"` to build an app using typescript, define the app state like this:

```
export interface IRoleState {
    data: API.RoleItem,
    menus: API.MenuItem,
}
```

when I define the state:

```
const RoleModel: IRoleModel = {
    namespace: 'roles',
    state: {
        data: {
            id: 1,
            name: ''
        },
        menus: {}
    }
}
```

the IDE told that warning:

```
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'MenuItem': id, name, children
```

what should I do to give the init state of the menu? I just want to give the empty object because I still did not know the init value of the menu. should I must write it like this?

```
const RoleModel: IRoleModel = {
    namespace: 'roles',
    state: {
        data: {
            id: 0,
            name: ''
        },
        menus: {
            id: 0,
            name: 'default',
            children: []
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: Generally the best approach would be to only initialize the object once you have the initial menu value. Otherwise, trying to assign a value that doesn't match the specified type can be confusing for consumers and might cause type problems later. Doable, but only if there's no other option IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely must insert a non-conforming value for `state.menus`, you can force TS to believe it's the right thing:

```js
const RoleModel: IRoleModel = {
    namespace: 'roles',
    state: {
        data: {
            id: 1,
            name: ''
        },
        menus: {} as API.MenuItem // casts empty object as expected type
    }
}
```